# How to run docker-compose inside VS Code devcontainer

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

I have this multi-container project comprised of 3 NestJS and 1 dotnet5.0 application. Besides the applications, the project depends on a RabbitMQ and an InfluxDB services (running as pure docker images)

The `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0
    container_name: influxdb
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
    expose:
      - '8086'
    volumes:
      - ./data/influxdb2/data:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - ./data/influxdb2/config:/etc/influxdb2

  rabbitmq:
    hostname: 'rabbitmq'
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'

  microservice1:
    image: microservice1
    container_name: microservice1
    depends_on: [rabbitmq, influxdb]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/microservice1/Dockerfile

  microservice2:
    image: microservice2
    container_name: microservice2
    depends_on: [rabbitmq, influxdb]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/microservice2/Dockerfile

  microservice3:
    image: microservice3
    container_name: microservice3
    depends_on: [rabbitmq, influxdb]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/microservice3/Dockerfile

  microservice4:
    image: microservice4
    container_name: microservice4
    depends_on: [rabbitmq, influxdb]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/microservice4/Dockerfile
```

I want to move the whole dev. environment to the new VS Code devcontainers but I'm not quite getting how to work with dependencies (like rabbitmq and influxdb here).

Ideally, I'd open the repo in a devcontainer with both nodejs and dotnet SDKs to be able to run the microservices during development. But, I don't want to also install influxdb and rabbitmq into the devcontainer as I want to leverage the existing (and convenient) docker images.

Problem is, once I open the repo inside the devcontainer there's no way to interact with docker-compose from the inside (as docker/docker-compose is not available inside the devcontainer).

Is it possible to interact with Docker engine on the host from inside the container? So I can simply have a `dev.sh` script that can simply `up` the rabbitmq and influxdb dependencies and then launch whatever microservice I want to run?

Maybe I'm getting it all wrong but I couldn't find a clear explanation on how to mix VS Code devcontainers and docker-compose files (with image-based dependencies).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

vscode can only use one service as "the workspace" where the IDE runs. Just like when working locally you are on the IDE and the other services run in other containers.

None of your current services seem "good" for being the IDE workspace, so you would have to add that one. That would be "just like" your host machine, but in the container.

You can use [multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case) so you can avoid changing your current `docker-compose.yml` while being able to add your new service.

So, part I:

1. Create a second `docker-compose.yml` file (maybe: `docker-compose.workspace.yml`)
2. Add one single service to that file, maybe call it "workspace". vscode Remote part will run there. What image? You may use one [vscode's precooked ones](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-dev-containers).
3. On `.devcontainer.json` point to both files and define the workspace service:

```json
...
  "dockerComposeFile": [
    "docker-compose.yaml",
    "docker-compose.workspace.yaml"
  ],
  "service": "workspace",
...
```

Ok. So that gives you the workspace container and everything else on the side. That gets us to the other part of the question:

> Is it possible to interact with Docker engine on the host from inside the container? So I can simply have a dev.sh script that can simply up the rabbitmq and influxdb dependencies and then launch whatever microservice I want to run?

First, if you want the docker & docker-compose commands you have to install the packages. Some images have them builtin, others not. You may use your own image, etc.

But that is not enough. You workspace container is ignorant of the host's docker. But it is easy enough to fix. Just add a volume mount:

```
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

On the workspace service. That way vscode will "see" your host's docker and operate with it.

Beware that it is still the host's docker, so you may get into trouble with paths, etc depending on what you do.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to use "docker compose" plugin rather than "docker-compose"?

Answer (score 4):

I recently started to muddle through this myself and will share what I have working. I am still futzing with the permissions, but running as root, everything is fine. So, as near as I can tell, you do not need to change anything in your working `docker-compose.yml` file. Mine looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: sleep infinity
        user: root
        ports:
            - 5001:5001
            - [snip]
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myRootpwd32
```

Taken from the standard `Dockerfile` generated by VS Code (truncated for brevity):

```
# [Choice] .NET version: 5.0, 3.1, 2.1
ARG VARIANT="3.1"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/dotnet:0-${VARIANT}

# [Option] Install Node.js
ARG INSTALL_NODE="true"
ARG NODE_VERSION="lts/*"
RUN if [ "${INSTALL_NODE}" = "true" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} 2>&1"; fi
```

And finally the `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "C# (.NET)",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/MemberCore",

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },

    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
        "wakatime.vscode-wakatime",
        "fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer",
        "adrianwilczynski.add-reference",
        "kreativ-software.csharpextensions",
        "k--kato.docomment",
        "pranaygp.vscode-css-peek",
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "patcx.vscode-nuget-gallery",
        "derivitec-ltd.vscode-dotnet-adapter"
    ],
}
```

The key is obviously in the `dockerComposeFile` line, which lets you re-use what you've already written there.

A lot of my information came from this repo: https://github.com/0916dhkim/vscode-devcontainer-tutorial which has a full working example from scratch.

Comment: Yes but that simply runs the docker containers declared in the docker compose from within the dev container (but actually leveraing the host's docker engine). That doesn't add any extra benefit. I mean, I could simply run `docker-compose` from my machine without spinning a dev container. I want to run my microservices without docker for development (meaning I need to install node SDKs, Python, dotnet, whatever). Docker compose would only be used to spin up databases, brokers and dependencies like that.

Comment: I think I see. You're actually wanting to have the devcontainer have its own instance of Docker and spin up containers "inside" the container?

Comment: No, I just want to leverage the host's Docker engine to spin up containers (just dependencies like databases, brokers and such) while running the actual microservices inside the devcontainer (without Docker).

Comment: Then I still think we're on the right track.  Use the `docker-compose.yml` to spin up the container-based dependencies (Rabbit, db), and similarly to my "app" service in my example, use the Dockerfile to build the devcontainer for your microservice that includes your dev tools like node, npm, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add Docker as a feature to your devcontainer.json:

"features": {
"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {}
}

This will allow access to the docker socket on the host.

Working example: [devcontainer.json](https://github.com/playingfield/ansible_role_web/blob/main/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json)